# 2d array table for LCS

Tags: c++, vector

I have written code to solve the Longest Common Subsequence problem.Just need the 2D table of m X w dimensions to be defined. I had defined it as a global variable but it threw a capacity exceeded error.

```
#define FOR(i,n) for( i = 0; i < n ; ++ i)
int LCS(const char M[],int m, const char W[], int w)
{
    // m length of M w length of W
    int ans,min,i,j;
    // lcs table needs to be defined with required dimensions 
    min = ( m >= w ) ? w : m;

    FOR(i,m)
        FOR(j,w)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                lcs[i][j] = 0; // repetitive
            else if (M[i] == W[j] )
                lcs[i][j] = lcs[i-1][j-1] + 1;
            else
                lcs[i][j] = max(lcs[i-1][j],lcs[i][j-1]);
        }

        return (min == lcs[m-1][w-1]);
}
```

I'm considering using  vector of vector but then is it possible to define the size as m x w at the same time ? A normal

```
vector < vector <int> > lcs
```

would not suffice as I want to pre define the vectors and access it using the subscript operator as in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can as long as all inner vectors should be at the same size.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v(9000, std::vector<int>(9000, 23));
```

The first argument is the `count` (how many objects should initially be in the `vector`) and the second argument is the value used to initialize each of those. In the above case you end up with 9000 vectors each filled with 9000 times the number 23.

A complete list of `vector` constructors [is here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: OK.WIthout object name form is allowed

Comment: @DamnDev Sorry, I don't understand. What form is allowed when which object name is not present?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
vector<vector<int>> lcs(m, vector<int>(w));
```

to create a "vector of vector" of size `m x w`.

This works because of the two parameter std::vector constructor:

```
vector(size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type());
```

which takes the size `n` as its first parameter and the value `val` as its second parameter, so there are `m` copies of `vector<int>(w)`, that is `m` copies of `vector<int>` of size `w` (with default values `int()`, which is 0).

*References*:

- [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > lcs( m, std::vector<int>( w ) );
```